# Hyper-V: cannot create Shared Virtual Hard Disk on Windows 11 Enterprise 22H2

Tags: ubuntu, windows, hyper-v, shared-disk

An **Ubuntu 20.04 VM** runs on **Windows 11 Enterprise 22H2**. The **creation of a "Shared Virtual Hard Disk" fails** with the following error: "*The storage where the virtual hard disk is located does not support virtual hard disk sharing*".

I faced reliability issues with file sharing through the "Extended Session" feature of Hyper-V, especially with large files. I then tried to add a shared virtual drive to the Ubuntu VM: it would be formated with NTFS and shared with its Windows host or other guest VMs.

**Procedure followed and results obtained** are the following:

1. Create a new SCSI controller that will support the "Shared Virtual Hard Disk": **OK**
2. Start the procedure to add a "Shared Drive": **OK**
3. Go through the first steps of drive creation using the "New Virtual Hard Disk Wizard", i.e. define format=VDHX, type=Dynamic Expanding, disk name, location and size: **OK**
4. Click on "Finish" without any error: **OK**
5. Clicking on "**Apply**": **fails with the above mentioned error**.

**Note 1**: I saw another procedure where one first creates a regular virtual disk then changes it to a shared drive using a "+" sign near the newly created disk. Yet this "+" sign is not available in my configuration.

**Note 2**: I do not have admin rights on this machine, which is why I locate my Hyper-V VMs and virtual disks in a subfolder of my user folder.

**My questions:**

1. Is there someting wrong with this procedure?
2. Am I facing a known limitation?
3. Is what I want to achieve primarily (share large files with Windows host) feasible this way?
4. Is there a better way (other than Samba) to achieve it?